# SciPyを使ったCSRNetのコードを実行するとgaussian_filterでエラーが出る

Tags: python, 機械学習, scipy

## やりたいこと

Crowd countingのモデル [CSRNet](https://qiita.com/HKondo0804/items/af48a3c86b96bbc10b80)用に[Beijing BRTデータセット](https://github.com/XMU-smartdsp/Beijing-BRT-dataset)の人物頭部位置のアノテーションからdensity mapのアノテーションを作成したい。

## エラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/directory/make_dataset.py", line 67, in <module>
    k = gaussian_filter_density(k)
  File "/path/to/directory/make_dataset.py", line 38, in gaussian_filter_density
    density += gaussian_filter(pt2d, sigma, mode='constant')
  File "/path/to/directory/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py", line 368, in gaussian_filter
    gaussian_filter1d(input, sigma, axis, order, output,
  File "/path/to/directory/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/_filters.py", line 269, in gaussian_filter1d
    lw = int(truncate * sd + 0.5)
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

最初の数画像はうまく行くのですが、途中で上記のエラーが出て実行ストップしてしまいます。

## コード

### 実行ファイル

`make_dataset.py`

```
import h5py
import scipy.io as io
import PIL.Image as Image
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter 
import scipy
import json
from matplotlib import cm as CM
# from image import *
# from model import CSRNet
import torch

def gaussian_filter_density(gt):
    print(gt.shape)
    density = np.zeros(gt.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    gt_count = np.count_nonzero(gt)
    if gt_count == 0:
        return density

    pts = np.array(list(zip(np.nonzero(gt)[1], np.nonzero(gt)[0])))
    leafsize = 2048
    # build kdtree
    tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(pts.copy(), leafsize=leafsize)
    # query kdtree
    distances, locations = tree.query(pts, k=4)

    print('generate density...')
    for i, pt in enumerate(pts):
        pt2d = np.zeros(gt.shape, dtype=np.float32)
        pt2d[pt[1],pt[0]] = 1.
        if gt_count > 1:
            sigma = (distances[i][1]+distances[i][2]+distances[i][3])*0.1
        else:
            sigma = np.average(np.array(gt.shape))/2./2. #case: 1 point
        density += gaussian_filter(pt2d, sigma, mode='constant')
    print('done.')
    return density


# set the root to Beijing BRT
root = '/path/to/Beijing-BRT-dataset'

#now generate the ground truth
train_path = os.path.join(root, 'train', 'frame')
test_path = os.path.join(root, 'test', 'frame')
path_sets = [train_path, test_path]

img_paths = []
for path in path_sets:
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpg')):
        img_paths.append(img_path)

for img_path in img_paths:
    print(img_path)
    mat = io.loadmat(img_path.replace('.jpg', '.mat').replace('frame', 'ground_truth'))
    img = plt.imread(img_path)
    k = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))    
    gt = mat['loc']

    for i in range(len(gt)):
        if int(gt[i][1]) < img.shape[0] and int(gt[i][0]) < img.shape[1]:
            k[int(gt[i][1]), int(gt[i][0])] = 1
            print(k)
    k = gaussian_filter_density(k)
    with h5py.File(img_path.replace('.jpg', '.h5').replace('frame', 'ground_truth'), 'w') as hf:
            hf['density'] = k
```

コードはこちらの[CSRNet開発者のコード](https://github.com/leeyeehoo/CSRNet-pytorch)を[Qiita記事](https://qiita.com/HKondo0804/items/af48a3c86b96bbc10b80)や[こちらのサイト](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/02/building-crowd-counting-model-python/)を参考に、Python 3用にコードを修正し、元のコードはShanghaiTechデータセット用に書かれているのでBeijing BRTデータセット用にさらにコードを変更したものです。

## 環境

- Windows 11上のWSL2, Ubuntu 22.04
- Python 3.10（venv使用）
- SciPy 1.10.0

## エラー再現方法

上記Pythonコードの他に[GitHub](https://github.com/XMU-smartdsp/Beijing-BRT-dataset)からBeijing BRTデータセット（画像とアノテーション`.mat`ファイルなど）をダウンロードした上で`make_dataset.py`を実行しました。

## その他

質問に不備などありましたら訂正致しますので教えていただければ幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

コードの６７行目

```
density += gaussian_filter(pt2d, sigma, mode='constant')
```

で渡した`sigma`の値が無限大になっていることがエラーの原因であることがわかりました。

`sigma`の値を適切な上限値に制限することでエラーを回避できます。
例：

```
sigma = (distances[i][1]+distances[i][2]+distances[i][3])*0.1
```

を

```
res = min(gt.shape)  # The resolution here is the number of pixels in vertical or horizontal, whichever is smaller

sigma = min((distances[i][1]+distances[i][2]+distances[i][3])*0.1, res * 10)  # To prevent an overflow error
```

に変更する。